# Ignoring all pgsql comments with diff while comparing two schema files

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, diff

What is the right diff command syntax to ignore all pgsql comments, both single line '--' and multiple lines '/**/' while comparing the two sql dump files ?

I have tried this but it didn't work.

diff -b -I '^(--C|/*| *)' schema1.sql schema2.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk to format the data and redirect into diff:

```
diff <(awk '!/^--/ && blnk!=1 && !/^\/\*/ { print $0 } /^\/\*/ { blnk=1 } /^\*\// { blnk=0 } ' schema1.sql) <(awk '!/^--/ && blnk!=1 && !/^\/\*/ { print $0 } /^\/\*/ { blnk=1 } /^\*\// { blnk=0 } ' schema2.sql)
```

Using awk, we set a marker value blnk to 1 if we encounter a line starting with */ and then set it to 0 when we encounter a line starting with */ Then when a line doesn't begin with a -- and blnk is not 1, we print the line. This is done for both schema1.sql and schema2.sql before the output in redirected back for the diff comparison.